# Logged in User's SID in Windows service Win 7

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I am trying to find SID of current logged in user on Win 7.
I am using

```
string _CurrentUser = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User.Value.ToString();
```

When I run it in Console app, I get the user's SID as "S-1-5-21-670676956-2645971461-1681047478-500", but when I put the above line in a windows service, I get a different SID i.e. "S-1-5-18" I understand that Windows service runs as a different account. 
How do I get the User's SID in Windows service, same as the one I am getting in Console app?

Also when I run the same code in Win XP, Windows service and Console app gives the same SID unlike Win 7.

Comment: `S-1-5-18` is the SID for the Local System account. This _is_ the user that the service is running as.

Comment: @adrianbanks Correct, but how do I get the logged in user's SID in Windows service (Win 7)

Comment: Which "logged in user"? The Windows service can run when there is nobody logged in. It can also run when there are several people logged in. Think of it as the service running in its own "desktop" (although it runs headless), so it has no concept of the "current" logged in user.

Comment: Hmmm, I am little confused now, why do I get the same SID in WinXP for service and console app. Take this scenario in Win 7, I logged in with my credentials, now I want to find my SID using windows service. How do I get it?

Comment: Windows Vista and up has console context isolated from the service context.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use terminal services to list users which are logged via console or remote desktop, check which one is on the console, and get it's sid based on that.

Here is nice .NET library to do this:

http://code.google.com/p/cassia/

Comment: This is a great thing, I will have to go through its distribution doc so that I can use it legally. I would prefer to use standard/native .net library to achieve my task. Any ideas?